# Why is this integer descelating infinitely?

Tags: c++, while-loop, sfml

I am trying to make a simple hangman game using SFML and C++ but I am running into an issue iterating down for each time a correct letter is not inputted, but a letter is inputted. What seems to happen every time is a constant loop that reduces bodyParts to 0 and then to negative infinity. When the game begins there is no keyboard input, why does it iterate down infinitely? Thanks!

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static String WORD = "word";
    char letter1 = '_';
    char letter2 = '_';
    char letter3 = '_';
    char letter4 = '_';
    int bodyParts = 6;
    int xoffset = 150;
    int yoffset = 50;
    bool playing = true;
    bool inputLetter = false;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(400, 400), "Hangman - through the might of SFML");
    // Word Bank
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("/home/brandon/Dropbox/Brandon-Nick/C++/Qt-Creator/SFML/Hangman/Hangman/arial.ttf"))
    {
        // error...
    }
    Text letterbankText;
    letterbankText.setFont(font);
    letterbankText.setString("---LETTER BANK---");
    letterbankText.setCharacterSize(14);
    letterbankText.setColor(Color::White);
    letterbankText.setPosition(0, 50);
    Text letterbank;
    letterbank.setFont(font);
    letterbank.setString(" \t _ _ _ _ ");
    letterbank.setCharacterSize(14);
    letterbank.setColor(Color::White);
    letterbank.setPosition(0, 75);
    // Hangman character
    CircleShape head(50.f);
    head.setFillColor(Color::Green);
    head.setPosition(xoffset, yoffset + 0);
    RectangleShape body(Vector2f(10, 90));
    body.setPosition(xoffset + 45, yoffset + 100);
    body.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
    RectangleShape rightArm(Vector2f(60, 10));
    rightArm.setPosition(xoffset + 55, yoffset + 120);
    rightArm.setFillColor(Color::Magenta);
    RectangleShape leftArm(Vector2f(60, 10));
    leftArm.setPosition(xoffset - 15, yoffset + 120);
    leftArm.setFillColor(Color::Yellow);
    RectangleShape leftLeg(Vector2f(60, 10));
    leftLeg.setPosition(xoffset - 15 + 65, yoffset + 190);
    leftLeg.setFillColor(Color::White);
    leftLeg.rotate(135);
    RectangleShape rightLeg(Vector2f(60, 10));
    rightLeg.setPosition(xoffset - 15 + 75, yoffset + 182.5);
    rightLeg.setFillColor(Color::Cyan);
    rightLeg.rotate(45);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        while(playing){
            inputLetter = false;
            window.clear();
            while(inputLetter == false){
                // Input letter guess
                if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
                {
                    letter1 = 'W';
                    letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                    inputLetter = true;
                }
                else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::O))
                {
                    letter2 = 'o';
                    letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                    inputLetter = true;
                }
                else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::R))
                {
                    letter3 = 'r';
                    letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                    inputLetter = true;
                }
                else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
                {
                    letter4 = 'd';
                    letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                    inputLetter = true;
                }
                else if(Event::KeyPressed){
                    bodyParts -= 1;
                    inputLetter = true;
                }
                else
                    inputLetter = false;
            }
            switch(bodyParts){
                case 6:
                    window.draw(head);
                case 5:
                    window.draw(body);
                case 4:
                    window.draw(leftArm);
                case 3:
                    window.draw(rightArm);
                case 2:
                    window.draw(leftLeg);
                case 1:
                    window.draw(rightLeg);
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << bodyParts;
            }
            window.draw(letterbankText);
            window.draw(letterbank);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use a text interface, with no sfml?

Comment: That works fine (IE cin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed a few things, first of all

```
else if (sf::Event::KeyPressed){
    bodyParts -= 1;
    inputLetter = true;
}
```

Remove the above and let `window.pollEvent()` handle events:

```
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    if (event.type == Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
        handleInputs(event.key.code, true);
}
```

In the above code, I let a function take care of player inputs `handleInputs()`

Also, `while(playing)` is not necessary and should be removed, because `while(window.isOpen())` is already the game loop.

You forgot to `break` in the switch statement, ending up drawing all body parts before you could even see any of it. I suggest creating variables of type `bool` that decides whether to draw each body part:

```
bool drawHead       = false;
bool drawBody       = false;
bool drawRightArm   = false;
bool drawLeftArm    = false;
bool drawRightLeg   = false;
bool drawLeftLeg    = false;
```

and turning them on based on body parts:

```
switch (bodyParts){
        case 6:
            drawHead = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            drawBody = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            drawLeftArm = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            drawRightArm = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            drawLeftLeg = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            drawRightLeg = true;
            break;
        default:
            ;//cout << bodyParts;
}
```

finally drawing them:

```
window.draw(letterbankText);
window.draw(letterbank);
if (drawHead) window.draw(head);
if (drawBody) window.draw(body);
if (drawRightArm) window.draw(rightArm);
if (drawLeftArm) window.draw(leftArm);
if (drawRightLeg) window.draw(rightLeg);
if (drawLeftLeg) window.draw(leftLeg);
```

<kbd>[Full code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5226468305adc1ea)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your eloquent and helpful answer. The reason I do not have breaks is because I want all the body parts to be drawn at the start and removed as each answer is incorrect (wrong letter). Each time an answer is inputted, bodyparts decrements and starts at a lower tier in the switch statement.

Comment: I like your approach though!

Answer (score 1):

'playing' is set to true in the beginning. Maybe it needs to be set to false somewhere to come out of the inner loop. Or some other loop exit conditional statement may be needed.

Comment: But shouldn't bodyParts remain constant? When the game begins there is not keyboard input, why does it iterate down infinitely?

Comment: Pollevent documentation says 'This function is not blocking: if there's no pending event then it will return false and leave event unmodified.'

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes I needed to use pollevent as part of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I had to place my keyboard listener within the pollevent event. Here is the updated code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
static String WORD = "word";

char letter1 = '_';
char letter2 = '_';
char letter3 = '_';
char letter4 = '_';

int bodyParts = 6;


int xoffset = 150;
int yoffset = 50;

bool playing = true;
bool inputLetter = false;


RenderWindow window(VideoMode(400, 400), "Hangman - through the might of SFML");

// Word Bank
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile("/home/brandon/Dropbox/Brandon-Nick/C++/Qt-Creator/SFML/Hangman/Hangman/arial.ttf"))
{
    // error...
}

Text letterbankText;
letterbankText.setFont(font);
letterbankText.setString("---LETTER BANK---");
letterbankText.setCharacterSize(14);
letterbankText.setColor(Color::White);
letterbankText.setPosition(0, 50);

Text letterbank;
letterbank.setFont(font);
letterbank.setString(" \t _ _ _ _ ");
letterbank.setCharacterSize(14);
letterbank.setColor(Color::White);
letterbank.setPosition(0, 75);


// Hangman character
CircleShape head(50.f);
head.setFillColor(Color::Green);
head.setPosition(xoffset, yoffset + 0);

RectangleShape body(Vector2f(10, 90));
body.setPosition(xoffset + 45, yoffset + 100);
body.setFillColor(Color::Blue);

RectangleShape rightArm(Vector2f(60, 10));
rightArm.setPosition(xoffset + 55, yoffset + 120);
rightArm.setFillColor(Color::Magenta);

RectangleShape leftArm(Vector2f(60, 10));
leftArm.setPosition(xoffset - 15, yoffset + 120);
leftArm.setFillColor(Color::Yellow);

RectangleShape leftLeg(Vector2f(60, 10));
leftLeg.setPosition(xoffset - 15 + 65, yoffset + 190);
leftLeg.setFillColor(Color::White);
leftLeg.rotate(135);

RectangleShape rightLeg(Vector2f(60, 10));
rightLeg.setPosition(xoffset - 15 + 75, yoffset + 182.5);
rightLeg.setFillColor(Color::Cyan);
rightLeg.rotate(45);


while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if(event.type == Event::KeyPressed){
            if(event.key.code == Keyboard::W){
                letter1 = 'W';
                letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                inputLetter = true;
            }
            else if(event.key.code == Keyboard::O){
                letter2 = 'o';
                letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                inputLetter = true;
            }
            else if(event.key.code == Keyboard::R){
                letter3 = 'r';
                letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                inputLetter = true;
            }
            else if(event.key.code == Keyboard::D){
                letter4 = 'd';
                letterbank.setString(" \t" + String(letter1) + " " + letter2 + " " + letter3 + " " + letter4);
                inputLetter = true;
            }
            else
                bodyParts--;
        }
    }


    inputLetter = false;
    window.clear();



    switch(bodyParts){
    case 6:
        window.draw(head);
    case 5:
        window.draw(body);
    case 4:
        window.draw(leftArm);
    case 3:
        window.draw(rightArm);
    case 2:
        window.draw(leftLeg);
    case 1:
        window.draw(rightLeg);
        break;
    default:
        cout << bodyParts;
    }


    window.draw(letterbankText);
    window.draw(letterbank);
    window.display();



}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: See my example for better dealing with player inputs, you can have a function take care of it. Also, you forgot `break` in your switch